# Image Uploading in rails_api through devise Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm working on `rails_api` application , in it i used following gems for authentication

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
```

and for uploading image

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
```

I've generated the image column in `devise` user model and according to `carrierwave` documentation ,I updated my User model

**User Model**

```
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates_presence_of   :image
  validates_integrity_of  :image
  validates_processing_of :image
```

And in my `app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb` all defaults i.e including

```
 include CarrierWave::RMagick

 storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

When trying to upload image it shows the following exception

> ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError 795: unexpected token at
>   '����'

Any help will be appreciated